# How to create aab via air33?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, animate-cc

I want to create aab (bundle) using air 33 but it show following error.

`Bundle tool failed:Error while parsing the flags: Syntax error: flags should start with -- (Video)`

The command line that I used is:

`adt -package -target aab -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 myApp.aab myApp-app.xml myApp.swf assets Data`

I can create apk file replacing aab to apk. I try to google the error but couldn't find much. What does that error mean?

Comment: Probably wouldn't bother yet, it's still a bit experimental from Harman. I'd wait until they have ironed out all the issues. Stick with making 2 APK's for the moment.

Comment: I did try creating 1 APK for 32 bit and 1 APK for 64 bit but google keeps rejecting 32 bit APK.